# How can I assign specific values to annular sectors and display it as a colormap to describe distribution of flow rate?

Tags: graphics, charts

[image]

I want to generate the geometry as shown in the image above and assign values to the numbered regions. These values are indicative of distribution of flow rate from these different regions. Finally, I want to fill the regions according to their values and generate a colormap with colors representing the degree of distribution in all the regions.

Kindly help me with the problem.

Comment: `PieChart`, more or less.

Answer (score 2):

As Kuba comments the basic geometry might be generated with [`PieChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PieChart.html):

```
dat = Table[1, {i, {1, 4, 10}}, {n, i}]

PieChart[dat , SectorSpacing -> 0]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

[image]

Color for individual elements may be given with [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html):

```
dat[[2]] = Style[1, #] & /@ {Blue, Brown, Magenta, Black};

PieChart[dat, SectorSpacing -> 0]
```

[image]

I believe it is possible to solve your problem in this manner.  Please try it, and post again if you run into trouble.

Comment: I got the geometry right by using the following:                       PieChart[{{1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> Automatic, SectorSpacing -> 0, 
 SectorOrigin -> {{\[Pi]/2, "Clockwise"}, 0}]                                                      Now these specific sectors have specific values such as 1 -> 4.81, 
2 ->  9.46, 3 -> 5.67, 4 -> 7.64, 5 -> 7.09, 6 -> 6.46, 7 -> 5.04, 8 -> 12.14, 9 -> 7.80, 10 -> 8.90, 11 ->  5.99, 12 -> 3.62, 13 -> 5.52, 14 ->  3.86, 15 -> 5.99. I want these values to be depicted by a colorcode...!!